# Spring Data MongoDB Index Query on Sub Document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

In the [MongoDB Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-AdditionalNotes) we've got the following example:

```
db.factories.insert( { name: "xyz", metro: { city: "New York", state: "NY" } } );
db.factories.ensureIndex( { metro : 1 } );
// this query can use the above index:
db.factories.find( { metro: { city: "New York", state: "NY" } } );
```

I'm currently looking for a solution to archieve this query in spring data. My first approach was

```
Query.query(Criteria.where("metro")
    .andOperator(Criteria.where("city").is("New York")
    .and("state").is("NY")))
```

but this results in the following query

```
{ "metro" : { } , "$and" : [ { "city" : "New York" , "state" : "NY"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution by fiddling around:

```
Query.query(Criteria.where("metro").is(
    Query.query(
        Criteria.where("city").is("New York")
        .and("state").is("NY")).getQueryObject()
    )
)
// results in { metro: { city: "New York", state: "NY" } }
```

Hopefully this is the right way to do it...